# Struct arrays pointers issue

Tags: c, pointers, struct

could somedoby clarify some basic C language moments.

```
struct key {
    char *name;
    int value;
};

struct key first_key_array[] = {
    {"abc", 5},
    {"xyz", 6},
    {"def", 7}
};

struct key second_key_array[] = {
    {"what", 200},
    {"when", 300}
};

struct data {
    struct key **key_array;
};

struct data all_key_arrays[] = {
    {first_key_array},
    {second_key_array}
};
```

I could directly access first_key_array[0]:

```
printf("%s %d", first_key_array[0].name, first_key_array[0].value);
```

But access via all_key_arrays does not work:

```
printf("%s %d", all_key_arrays[0].key_array[0].name, all_key_arrays[0].key_array[0].value);
```

Could somebody share any ideas?

Comment: The initializer for `struct data all_key_arrays[] = ` is ill-formed. Your compiler should tell you about this. If you don't see any compiler messages then you need to figure out how to stop disabling your compiler's output messages .  You need to fix the compiler messages before trying to run the program.

Comment: The fix will be that `struct key **key_array;` should be `struct key *key_array;`, although this design has a problem that if you go in via `all_key_arrays` then there is no way of checking you don't access past the end of wherever it is pointing

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the initializer for *all_key_arrays* to:

```
struct data all_key_arrays[] = {
    first_key_array,
    second_key_array
};
```

or

```
struct data all_key_arrays[] = {
    &first_key_array[0],
    &second_key_array[0]
};
```

Explanation -- *all_key_arrays* is an array pointers, so the values you initialize the array to should be, well, pointers.